# Modify raycast?

Tags: unity, raycasting

In my script, the raycast starts from a camera, and moves forward. I need to modify it to make it start from a bit far from the camera, without changing the direction.

```
Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit,100))   
{
    print("Ray hit something !");
}
else 
{
    print (" Nothing ");
}
```

Comment: ...so add a multiple of `fwd` to the raycast origin, currently `transform.position`. Have you encountered any trouble implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quite simple.

When you cast your ray, you provide `transform.position` as your starting point. Simply change this to your desired position.

A good way to do this would be to simply add the difference to your `transform.position`. As *DCGregory* points out, you should use a multiple of `fwd`, as this already represents the local direction you intend to follow.

---

Note that in your answer, I could not tell what you meant by "a bit far". Do you want the ray to come from *behind* the camera, or start somewhat in front of it? *It does not matter*. The only difference, in the code, is if we are *adding* the offset or *subtracting* it.

**In front of camera:**

```
<summary>Approximately how far should the ray be from the camera, in game units.</summary>
float distanceFromCamera = 1.0f;
<summary>The local forward direction.</summary>
Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
<summary>Placeholder for ray cast information.</summary>
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast((transform.position + (fwd * distanceFromCamera), 
    fwd, out hit,100)) 
{
    print("Ray hit something !");
} 
else 
{
    print (" Nothing ");
}
```

**Behind camera:**

```
<summary>Approximately how far should the ray be from the camera, in game units.</summary>
float distanceFromCamera = 1.0f;
<summary>The local forward direction.</summary>
Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
<summary>Placeholder for ray cast information.</summary>
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast((transform.position - (fwd * distanceFromCamera), 
    fwd, out hit,100)) 
{
    print("Ray hit something !");
} 
else 
{
    print (" Nothing ");
}
```

---

As a final note, I am *assuming* `print(string)` is a custom method. Typically, I would simply replace these with the in-house `Debug.Log(string)`.